# The set of real solutions to an equation

Tags: proof-verification, exponential-function

$$4^x - 7(2^{\frac{x-3}{2}}) = 2^{-x}$$
Set of real solutions is in which interval:

1. $(-9, -2)$
2. $(0, 3]$
3. $(-2, 0]$
4. $(7, 12]$
5. $(3, 7]$

I tried the following. Dividing by $2^{-x}$ I get $2^{3x} - \frac{7\sqrt(2)}{4}2^{\frac{3x}{2}} - 1 = 0$. Substituing 
$$
2^{3x} = c
$$ and solving I get $c_1= 2\sqrt(2)$ and $c_2=-\frac{\sqrt(2)}{4}$ and for $x$ I get $\frac{1}{2}$. That's not even in the given line. What is wrong with the calculations. What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

$$4^x-7\left(2^{\frac{x-3}{2}}\right)=2^{-x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$2^{2x}-7\left(2^{\frac{x-3}{2}}\right)=2^{-x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$2^{3x}-7\left(2^{\frac{3x}{2}-\frac{3}{2}}\right)=1\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $y=-7\left(2^{\frac{3x}{2}-\frac{3}{2}}\right)$:

---

$$\frac{8y^2}{49}+y=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y^2+\frac{49y}{8}=\frac{49}{8}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y^2+\frac{49y}{8}+\frac{2401}{256}=\frac{3969}{256}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left(y+\frac{49}{16}\right)^2=\frac{3969}{256}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y+\frac{49}{16}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{3969}{256}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y+\frac{49}{16}=\pm\frac{63}{16}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y=\pm\frac{63}{16}-\frac{49}{16}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Notice that the positive one from our $y$ soution,

has no solution since for all $z\in\mathbb{R},2^z>0$ and $-\frac{1}{8}<0$:

---

$$y=-\frac{63}{16}-\frac{49}{16}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y=-7\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-7\left(2^{\frac{3x}{2}-\frac{3}{2}}\right)=-7\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$2^{\frac{3x}{2}-\frac{3}{2}}=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{3x}{2}-\frac{3}{2}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{3(x-1)}{2}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x-1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $$4^x-7\cdot 2^{\frac{x-3}{2}}=2^{-x}$$
$$(2\sqrt2)2^{3x}-7\cdot 2^{\frac{3x}{2}}-2\sqrt2=0$$
let $2^{\frac{3x}{2}}=t$, 
$$(2\sqrt 2)t^2-7t-2\sqrt 2=0$$
$$t=\frac{-(-7)\pm\sqrt{(-7)^2-4(2\sqrt 2)(-2\sqrt 2)}}{2(2\sqrt2)}=\frac{7\pm9}{4\sqrt 2}$$ but $t(=2^{\frac{3x}{2}})>0$ hence, one should get 
$$2^{\frac{3x}{2}}=\frac{7+9}{4\sqrt 2}=2\sqrt 2=2^{\frac{3}{2}}$$
$$\implies \frac{3x}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$$ $$\color{red}{x=1}$$